# ComboBox SelectedItem not set with x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to figure out why I can't set the initial `SelectedItem` value on my ComboBox if I bind with `ItemsSource="{x:Bind [source]}"`.
This xaml works

```
<ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Sites, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedContractSite, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But when I change to the following xaml, the ComboBox contains the sites, but does not show the SelectedItem as the default. (In fact, it appears to flicker into view and then disappear).

```
<ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Sites, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedContractSite, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is the relevant code in the ViewModel. (I abbreviated the long Sites list.)

```
public List<string> Sites
{
    get
    {
        return new List<string>()
        {                
            "Miami",                
            "Texas"
        };
    }
}

private string _selectedContractSite = "Texas";
public string SelectedContractSite
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedContractSite;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _selectedContractSite, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedContractSite, Mode=TwoWay}"`. My Assumption is, `ViewModel` is alreay assigned as `ItemsSource` so it should just be property for any `ItemsBinding`. Again, Just an assumption.

Comment: @AVKNaidu, Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. The binding path doesn't resolve without the ViewModel included.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be related to code you haven't shown.

If I create a viewModel like this

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> Sites
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "Miami",
                "Texas"
            };
        }
    }

    private string _selectedContractSite = "Texas";

    public string SelectedContractSite
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedContractSite;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedContractSite != value)
            {
                _selectedContractSite = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedContractSite));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and then set up the codebehind like this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

Then the following XAML works as expected

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Sites, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedContractSite, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Note. I'm using `x:Bind` and referencing the ViewModel in both binding paths.

I suspect your confusion lies in the differences between `x:Bind` and `Binding`.
With `x:Bind` the root of the binding path is the page the control with the binding is on.
With `Binding` the root of the binding path is the `DataContext` of the page the control is on.
Mixing the two can get confusing. If you do need to use a combination of the two then set `this.DataContext = this;` in the page constructor so they both point to the same thing.

Comment: Was writing my Answer with exact explanation and examples. +1.

Comment: Thank you. I will dig deeper. The code you wrote seems identical to what i have, but some of it (setting the ViewModel, Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) is wrapped in the Template10 framework, so the devil may be in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new `List<string>` in the getter of the `Sites` property?

Try to create the source collection only *once*:

```
public List<string> Sites { get; } = new List<string>() { "Miami", "Texas" };
```